# Using AWS API Gateway+Lambda Without It becoming a Dependency

Tags: aws-lambda, dependencies, microservices, aws-api-gateway

There's no doubt to the benefits of API Gatway+Lambda for a micro-services.

My concern is what would happen if we decide to move off API Gateway+Lambda to ECS/Fargate, or even another Cloud.

There seems to be a consensus on using one Lambda function per route/action.

I have some theories about how to design using this approach such that the code can be unplugged from Lambda and plugged-in some where else.

I would also like to know what others in the community have done to achieve this? Has anyone attempted to move the API off Lambda and was able to successfully do it using XXXX design? What are the lessons there?

The language should not really matter to this discussion but we are using python3

Answer (score 0):

What you're facing right now has a name. It's called "vendor lock in". Pretty much nothing you can do about it.

However, I find it useful to treat AWS Lambda handler function as a controller in your web server. What would you do in your controller? You'd validate incoming data, pass it to service layer and then serialize response from the service and pass it back to API Gateway. Long story short, your handler function should not contain business logic, which makes it easy to migrate even from serverless to servers. It's also can be good because it leaves some place for optimization. If you end up seeing that your service layer architecture adds significant time to cold start, then just denormalize it to a single file. It'll work faster, but you'll sacrifice code maintainability. There is no silver bullet, software has always been about trade offs. :)

Comment: I am basically going to have Lambda pass the event and context objects to my python package and nothing more.  That package will have a translation class for AWS events/context, extract the JSON out of the request, then pass it along.
I'll deploy the Lambdas using CodePipeline / SAM Templates